# Find First Word matching from Given Text - Regex

Tags: c#, regex, cpu-word, replace

I want to find First Word matching from Given Text and replace with another word, using Regex.

> **Consider following string as an Example Text**
>
> *Which type is your item? i suppose that the item isn't a string, if so
>   you can override ToString() method in
>   the item class and use the jayant's
>   code.*

I want to search first "item" word in it and replace that with text "hello".  Remember i just want to replace first "item" word only and not all.

> **So output of above text would be something like following.**
>
> *Which type is your hello? i suppose that the item isn't a string, if so
>   you can override ToString() method in
>   the item class and use the jayant's
>   code.*

I am using C# Programming to do this and I would prefer to use Regex if possible.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Regex.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx) method with the 3rd parameter (maximum replacements):

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("item");
string result = rgx.Replace(str, "hello", 1);
```

See it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/CMhrU)

*(Though in this case you don't really need Regex because you are searching for a constant.)*

Comment: Thanks Man you saved my lot of time.

Comment: Do you know how to replace string when word uppercase/lowercase not matching?

Comment: @Jordon You can compile the Regex to be case-insenstive (eg: `new Regex("item", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to non-Regex alternatives, you can do something like this

```
public static string ReplaceOnce(this string input, string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    int index = input.IndexOf(oldValue);
    if (index > -1)
    {
        return input.Remove(index, oldValue.Length).Insert(index, newValue);
    }

    return input;
}
```

//

```
Debug.Assert("bar bar bar".ReplaceOnce("bar", "foo").Equals("foo bar bar"));
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to ignore case while doing this?

Comment: @Jordon, IndexOf has an overload that takes a `StringComparison` enum. You can use that overload to specify culture/casing matching rules (e.g., `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`).